# Use bar graphs as parameter filter in Tableau

Tags: parameters, data-visualization, tableau-api

I've created a parameter that changes a top 10 list of selected measure.
I also created a sheet with all the measures as bar graphs as shown in the image.

Is it possible for me to create some kind of filter where I select a measure in the bars which can change the parameter and the list?

Also, additionally, are there any other cool ways to select a box or a container that changes the parameter?

Appreciate your time

**Parameter:**

[image]

**Bars:**

[image]
or

**Bars-2:**

[image]

Comment: you need measure names as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to embed your visualization in a HTML page. Use whatever HTML and CSS you would like to allow the user to choose a parameter value, and then use a bit of JavaScript to set your parameter value, calling the workbook.changeParameterValueAsync() function from the Tableau JavaScript API.

This is not as simple as choosing some settings in Tableau Desktop, and obviously requires Tableau Server, Online or Public, but if you comfortable with a little HTML and JavaScript you can have a lot of control of the style and behavior of the chrome surrounding your visualization.

New Info
Since this answer, Tableau added parameter actions as a feature that are a simpler way to update parameters in response to user actions. The JavaScript API approach can still be useful to effect more elaborate responses.